# how to create a function for delete in php mysql?

Tags: php

i made a function to delete from more tables but it does not work?

```
//the 'id' is came through URL so why it does not work
$id = $_GET['id'];
del($id, "DELETE FROM `companies` WHERE id=$id");

function del($id, $query){
    try {
        $con->query($query);
        mysqli_commit($con);
        echo 'Deleted';
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        mysqli_rollback($con);
        echo $ex->getTraceAsString();
    }
}
```

Comment: **Variable SCOPE** The function knows nothing about `$con`

Comment: Why are you passing `$id` as a parameter when you already concatenate it into the second parameter

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$con` is defined in the same scope as you call the function then try this.

```
//the 'id' is came through URL so why it does not work
$id = $_GET['id'];
del($con, "DELETE FROM `companies` WHERE id=$id");

function del($con, $query){
    try {
        $con->query($query);

        mysqli_commit($con);
        echo 'Deleted';
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        mysqli_rollback($con);
        echo $ex->getTraceAsString();
    }
}
```

Comment: was just about to post this :)

Comment: :) I got a fast trigger finger tonight :) @Echtniet

Answer (score 0):

You should use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection attacks:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM `companies` WHERE id=?";
del($id, $sql, $con);

function del($id, $sql, $con){
    try {
        $result = $con->prepare($sql);
        $result->bind_param('i', $id);
        $result->execute() === true ? 'Successfully deleted' : 'Failed: '.$con->error;            
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        mysqli_rollback($con);
        echo $ex->getTraceAsString();
    }
}
```